# Change a color of a button from a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a form that contains a button, and I am trying to change the color of the button from a different thread that is in a different class (from yellow to red), but the color stays the same.

creating the object (this is in form1):

```
   Button b = new Button();
   b.Location = new Point(gameBoard[playerPosX,playerPosY].m_lbl.Location.X, gameBoard[playerPosX, playerPosY].m_lbl.Location.Y);   
   b.Parent = gameBoard[playerPosX, playerPosY].m_lbl;
   b.BackColor = Color.Black;
   b.Size = new Size(17, 17);
   b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
   b.Enabled = false;
   b.Text = "BASIC";
   this.Refresh();
   b.BringToFront();
   buildings.Add(new Structure("basic", b,playerPosX,playerPosY));
   Controls.Add(buildings[buildings.Count - 1].m_btn);
```

and this is the method that object's thread is doing :

```
public void basicOperation()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Form1.ChangeControlColor(Color.Yellow,m_btn);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Form1.ChangeControlColor(Color.Red,m_btn);
        }
    }
```

and here is form1.ChangeControlColor :

```
    delegate void SetColorCallBack(Color c,Button b);
    public static void ChangeControlColor(Color c,Button b)
    {
        if (b.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetColorCallBack d = new SetColorCallBack(ChangeControlColor);
            b.Invoke(d, new object[] { c,b });
        }
        else
        {
            b.BackColor = c;
            b.BringToFront();
            b.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

The following code does not work, and the button's color stays yellow.
I appreciate your time.

Comment: Any errors, did you step through the code, does the `else` clause ever fire?

Comment: No errors, when I debugged the code at the ChangeControlColor the if clause fires, in addition while debugging I saw that b.BackColor was once Color.Red, and once Color.Yellow repeatedly. but I didn't see any change in the form.

Comment: Also if the else statement gets hit, why would you expect to see the Red color when you immediately change it back to Yellow. Put a delay after setting to Red.

Comment: What a silly mistake, thank you it's working !.

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, WebForms or MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eliran,

Your multithreading code seems alright.

Because there is no delay between setting color to red and yellow, may be you don't see anything else than yellow.

Just try to add a delay between setting color yellow and red :

```
while (true)
    {
        Form1.ChangeControlColor(Color.Yellow,m_btn);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Form1.ChangeControlColor(Color.Red,m_btn);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
```

Regards

Comment: You mean you don't even need my answer. If you don't, I remove it